# Ping WSL2 by hostname from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After launching a WSL Kali instance, I can ping it by IP
from a Windows console, like this:

```
ping 172.31.37.123
```

but ... how can I *ping by name?*

I already changed the WSL hostname in `/etc/hostname`,
but I still can´t ping this name from a Windows console:

```
ping kali1
ping kali1.local
ping kali1.localdomain
```

None of this works.  Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I'd recommend, [If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/432493).  This isn't meant to be mean, just that the combination of Kali being *hard* to use and WSL2 having some subtle (but critical) differences from a virtual machine combine to create a very confusing environment. Highly recommend Ubuntu on WSL if you are just starting out. Not that you won't still have questions, but it's an easier distribution to use, especially given the amount of documentation out there for it.

Comment: I've found it quite convenient to run a Hyper-V VM using the "default switch" for networking, and then referring to it on Windows as `<VM hostname>.mshome.net`. Then, to expose a port in the network, I make use of [`netsh portproxy add v4tov4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy) using `<VM hostname>.mshome.net` as the listen address, this way I map a port in the VM to one in the host, and I don't have to deal with changing VM IPs like in WSL. Works great for SSH connections!

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to ping the WSL2 virtual network interface's address from Windows by name, you would need to add it to the *Windows* host file, rather than the Linux host file.

That can be found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.  You will need to edit it as an Administrator.

HOWEVER, there are a couple of a issues to be aware of (and better things to do than ping your WSL2 interface, anyway).

First, the WSL2 address changes every time it restarts (either on reboot or `wsl --shutdown`).  So you would need to either script the edit to your Windows host file to update it each time you start Kali, or update it manually.  This is a pain (and not needed).

Second, note that every WSL2 distribution that you have installed shares the same virtual NIC, so you are in reality addressing *any*/*all* installed distributions when you do this.  This may (or may not) have the results you expect.

##### Recommendation

As I've alluded to above, there's really no reason to `ping` WSL2.  Any service that you want to access in it will be accessible on the Windows host through `localhostForwarding`.  For example.  In Kali (assuming you have Python installed), run:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

And in your Windows browser, you can just open `localhost:8000`.

This works because, by default, WSL2 forwards any `localhost` port to WSL2 (assuming that the port isn't already bound in Windows).

So most any service (`ping` being an exception, since it doesn't use a TCP port, being ICMP) will be accessible via `localhost` anyway.

You can also verify this with a "service/port ping" of sorts in PowerShell to check that Python3 simple-server:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -Port 8000
```

Note that this will *not* work from other devices on the network (e.g. your phone).  If you need a solution for that, I can point you to other answers here on Super User.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... its good info but I need to know the IP from the WSL/vm from the vm-name... I mentioned ping but is for VNC use... and since the IP changes at each vm restart in the 172.*.*.* range... it does not help me very much... the only 'correct' solution I can foresee is of I can from the WSL update the host-windows-pc netbios record with the IP->Name of the WSL/vm... ;-)

Comment: @ZEE If you need to connect to WSL2 using VNC, then can't you just use the `localhost` name for that as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @ZEE If you need a different name, then add `127.0.0.1` to the Windows host file as mentioned above.  It's just that `ping`, of course, won't work this way since the *Windows* host will reply to the ping from *Windows*.  However, any TCP service should work with `127.0.0.1` as long as you use a port that isn't being used from Windows.

Comment: can't use vnc because the windows host already has the same port occupied (5900)... I had to change the vnc server port in the vm to 5901 and then connecting via localhost:5901 works fine... not a good solution if using several wsl-vms... I hope that in the future a mecanism to register the wsl-vm name in the windows-host netbios (like any other windows pc/vm) would be available... the process will be standard (as it should be) and much smoother...

Comment: @ZEE I had a feeling that the port was already in use.  Yes, have to use a different port.  And it's important to realize that Kali under WSL2 is *not* a VM.  Each distribution/instance is really a separate container (PID namespace) running *inside* a WSL2 VM.  Given that architecture, they will always share the same virtual NIC (network namespace) and more, meaning you'll always need to use a different port in each instance.